# Narrowing down a type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement something that satisfies a type, but a more specified version of that type.

```
type A = 'number' | 'string'

type B = {
    [prop: string]: (
        input: { [key: string]: A },
    ) => number
}

const test: B = {
    prop: (input: { a: string, b: string }) => 0
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Type '{ [key: string]: A; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: string; b: string; }': a, b
```

But I think it should compile because `{ a: string, b: string }` satisfies the constraint `{ [key: string]: A; }`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you really have those quotes around the types in `A`? That makes them string literal types, not `number` and `string`. Did you mean `type A = number | string`?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it cannot compile because `a: string, b: string` is not complying with the initial type `{ [key: string]: A }`.

There is no way angular know that `a` is a `string` and not a `number`, unless you tell it too (force it with a cast).

---

I would change your code and use a template to define the underlying values of `input`.

Like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygbwCgoSoBtAawhAC4odgAnASwwHMBdOgVwwowD2AdwwBuQgF8oAXigBDDCAB8MgsVJhGAsHQAU60qVZhuwOvigHD1ytSisoVEAIBmUBF3e2QHcddISADRWAJQyKhjcALYARhCM4hKEhKCQUADCqkSGcnQMLOx+pDF5TKxsoqSS4oQAxgIYDFDoDHTw6Sqy2RpaOlC6xqZh0ipEVoaMEMDcjBhQAAxFJEHVQA)

```
type B<T extends {
    [key: string]: unknown;
} = any> = {
    prop: (
        input: { 
            [key in keyof T]: T[key];
        },
    ) => number;
}

type C = {
    a: string;
    b: string;   
};

const test: B<C> = {
    prop: (input) => {

        return 0;
    },
};
```

---

[image]